# Calling a double array with parameters from field as method

Tags: java

disclaimer: Sorry if I used the terms incorrectly. It would be great if you could provide the correct terms (if I used them incorrectly!)

This is my class with the field and constructor:

```
double[] studentMathScores = {81.5,89.0,45.5,99.0,55.0,34.5,56.0,78.0,76.0,80.0};   
public StudentDashboard(double[] studentMathScores) 
    {
        this.studentMathScores = studentMathScores;
    }
```

How do I declare an object in my main class using studentMathScores?

```
StudentDashboard test = new StudentDashboard(studentMathScores);
```

`

Comment: what are you trying achieve.?

Comment: You cannot use a (non static) field of an object that does not yet exist.

Comment: I have a method called displayGradeSpread() used to sum up all the values in studentMathScores, convert them to a grade (e.g "A","B" etc) then display out in the console. But i'm unable to call the field "studentMathScores" as an object in my main class

Comment: I have no clue what are you asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to keep current constructor/class syntax you should declare in your main method.

`double[] studentMathScores = {81.5,89.0,45.5,99.0,55.0,34.5,56.0,78.0,76.0,80.0};`

In this case your declaration of `studentMathScores` in `StudentDashboard` shoul look like `double[] studentMathScores;`

Then have it like this:

`public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] studentMathScores = {81.5,89.0,45.5,99.0,55.0,34.5,56.0,78.0,76.0,80.0};
        StudentDashboard test = new StudentDashboard(studentMathScores);
    }
}`

2. If class syntax could be changed and `studentMathScores` can be static you can have it this way:

   ```
   public class StudentDashboard {

   static double[] studentMathScores ={81.5,89.0,45.5,99.0,55.0,34.5,56.0,78.0,76.0,80.0};

   public StudentDashboard()
   {
   }

   public static double[] getStudentMathScores() {
       return studentMathScores;
   }

   public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       StudentDashboard test = new StudentDashboard();
       double[] studentMathScores = StudentDashboard.getStudentMathScores();
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

I'll start of with the OOP concepts.

this is how Declaration is done:

```
StudentDashboard test;
```

Now i'll initialize the object by assigning it the constructor of the class. Also providing constructor the required parameter of an array:

```
StudentDashboard test = new StudentDashboard(studentMathScores);
```

now whenever i'll need to use this array from this object this is how it will be done.

```
double Singleindex = test.studentMathScores[1];
double[] wholeArray = test.studentMathScores;
```